# Construction of a special power series

Tags: derivatives, convergence-divergence, power-series, examples-counterexamples

If there exists a power series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nx^n$ whose radius of convergence is 1, and $\forall k\in \mathbb {N}, \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(a_nx^n)^{(k)} $ (namely the k-th term-by-term derivation) converges at the point $x=1$?
Furthermore, if the above eample exists, dose that mean for this example the convergence property is also satisfied with $x=-1$?

Comment: Try with $a_n = e^{-\log^2 n}$. 

That the series of $k$-th derivatives converges at $x=1$ means that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n n^k= 0$ and thus $\sum_n a_n p(n) z^n$ converges for all polynomial $p$ of degree $\le k-2$ and $|z|\le 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  But I still have a question. 
Where dose the restriction of degree $\leq k-2$ come from ?

Comment: $k-2$ is to reduce to that $\sum_n 1/n^2$ converges

Comment: Oh I got it!  Thank you very much!